# Вызов функции через onClick JS

Tags: javascript

Имеется таблица 3х3. При клике на какой-либо элемент он становится прозрачным. Получается сделать это прописав onClick="this.style.opacity='0';" в каждую из девяти ячеек. Помогите написать функцию, которая делает то же самое, но не лежит, а только вызывается из каждой ячейки.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте класс каждой ячейке, например `cell`. Затем в цикле повесьте обработчик на каждую ячейку

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.cell').forEach(function(cell) {
  cell.addEventListener('click', function() {
    cell.style.opacity = '0'
  })
})
```

```css
td {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td class="cell">2</td>
    <td class="cell">3</td>
    <td class="cell">4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cell">4</td>
    <td class="cell">5</td>
    <td class="cell">6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cell">7</td>
    <td class="cell">8</td>
    <td class="cell">9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

С помощью метода querySelectorAll в который передается css селектор, найдите все td. В нашем случае подойдет селектор **table td**

Затем пройдитесь по полученному массиву циклом forEach где каждый элемент это порядковый экземпляр **td**

Далее для каждого элемента добавляем событие onclick (клик) при котором происходит toogle свойства opacity

```js
document.querySelectorAll('table td').forEach(function(obj) {
  obj.onclick = function() {
    obj.style.opacity = (obj.style.opacity == 1 || obj.style.opacity == '' ? 0 : 1);
  }
});
```

```css
td {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```